# Could user accounts 4427 and 4428 be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

All the available evidences, strongest being the time of last activity ([2014-02-19 21:38:07Z](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/a-question-about-marriage#comment21700_11345)) of user 4427 and joining time (2014-02-19 21:43:17Z) of user [4428](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/4428), that I could find seem to testify the veracity of the [statement](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/11348/6) made by user 4428 i.e.:

> I am actually the user 4427

Other evidences being the that all questions (period) asked by the latter were duplicates of the former.

Is it possible for these two user accounts to be merged?

Although, I agree that there is a possibility, given the limited information available, that this isn't the case but the probability seems to be quite low and the risk, provided accounts couldn't be unmerged, could be taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged those accounts.

Typically the way we merge accounts is when someone uses the "contact us" form at the bottom of the page.  That way, a Community Manager can investigate and merge if advisable.